# Remove duplicate rows in SQL / finding the total payment

Tags: sql, duplicates, partition

Total_payments is the sum of all payements made by each playerid. How can get 1 row for each ID to appear with just the playerid and total_payments. I don't want duplicates.

```
SELECT playerid
     , payment_amount, SUM(payment_amount) OVER (PARTITION BY playerid) AS total_payment
FROM DEPOSIT$


| playerid | payment_amount| total_payment |
|:1002     |:10           :| 60           :|
|:1002     |:50           :| 60           :|
|:1003     |:40           :| 50           :|
|:1003     |:10           :| 50           :|
|:1004     |:10           :| 30           :|
|:1004     |:20           :| 30           :|
|:1006     |:100          :| 100          :|
|:1008     |:60           :| 60           :|
```

Thank you!

Comment: Remove payment_amount?

Comment: remove payment amout the anamlytoc function for sum and group by playerid

Comment: `sum(payment_amount) group by playerId`

Comment: sum(payment_amount) group by playerId does not work

Comment: Maybe demonstrate in a [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)

Comment: Just saying something doesn’t work is not that helpful. Why doesn’t it work? What result does it give you and how does that differ from what you are trying to achieve? Please update your question with sample data and the result you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

In general this would be the correct way - with a sum() and group by clause. Because you are grouping on playerid it will be unique for each playerid, and the total of the payment amounts will be summed it. This is really just a standard sql query for summing by some attribute.

```
SELECT 
    playerid,
    SUM(payment_amount) AS total_payment
FROM
    DEPOSIT$
GROUP BY
    playerid
```

perhaps you forgot the group by clause at the end?